# regexp.exec tildes

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy realizando un script para que cuando que consume un json, este lo guardo en una variable y de ahí busco una palabra clave.

Ejemplo:  Cómer
Si la busco con tilde funciona porque esta ahí pero si la busco sin tilde no la encuentra  estoy utilizando 
regexp.exec
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp

new RegExp("\b" + keywords + "\b", 'i');

Si alguien me puede guiar le agradezco.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar reemplazar las palabras con tilde

```js
keywordsSinTilde = keywords.replace(/á/gi, "a");
keywordsSinTilde = keywords.replace(/é/gi, "e");
keywordsSinTilde = keywords.replace(/í/gi, "i");
keywordsSinTilde = keywords.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
keywordsSinTilde = keywords.replace(/ú/gi, "u");

new RegExp("\b" + keywords + "\b"+"|"+"\b" + keywordsSinTilde + "\b", 'i');
```

Yo prefiero utilizar `RegExp.test()` que devuelve solo un `bool` en vez de un `array`

Comment: hola muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que no se puede reemplazar porque puede pasar que al buscar el contenido tenga palabras sin tilde  que omitió el webmaster, lo idea es que sea capaz de identificar con tilde o sin tilde.

Comment: Lo he editado, simplemente puedes buscar las dos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por su tiempo y por la ayuda  con lo que me dijiste de remplzar las tildes me  lo imagibana asi, como lo actualizaste quedo perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas gracias a los compañero que respondió y lo realice como lo sugiero solo ajuste el cambio de las tildes por este.

```js
var keyw = "fotóGrafía";
 keyw =  keyw.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
 console.log(keyw);
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que eso te cambia la ñ, y si mi respuesta te ayudó te agradecería que la marcaras como respuesta :)